# How do I reference a password from the setting.xml file in a pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

I've got a maven project that requires a password to login before performing any actions. Maven says that we should maintain passwords in a `server` stanza in the `settings.xml` file under the `~/.m2` directory, preferably with the password encrypted. What the documentation doesn't address is how to reference those passwords, specifically from the `pom.xml`. Does anyone know how that can be done? If it can't be referenced from the `pom` is it possible to reference it directly in the code?

Comment: Why do you need to? The POM should just reference the server id. Then the code looks up the server with this id in the settings and deduce the password.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Answer (score -1):

I have the same need. For me, I wanted to used an encrypted password as a config parameter to a plugin. I came across a plugin that reportedly supports this: com.github.shyiko.servers-maven-extension. Caveat: Untested by me as of yet.